# Another option aside from reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a situation where I am using reflection to call a method in order to provide the TResult of a projection expression that is unknown until run time. The TResult is included in the expression node as a string and I retrieve it with Type.GetType(). Once I have that Type I am able to cast the ExpressionNode back into an Expression a queryable.Select() can understand. While all of this works perfectly I wonder if there is a way other then reflection to accomplish the task of passing a parameter as a generic type for a method.

```
public static string ProcessExpressionNode<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> sourceQuery, ExpressionNode expressionNode)
        {
            var destType = Type.GetType(expressionNode.Type.GenericArguments[1].Name);

            var result = typeof(QueryableExtensions).GetMethod("ExecuteExpression", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .MakeGenericMethod(destType, typeof(TSource))
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { expressionNode, sourceQuery });


            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        }

internal static List<TResult> ExecuteExpression<TResult, TSource>(ExpressionNode expressionNode, IQueryable<TSource> source)
        {
            var result = source.Select(expressionNode.ToExpression<Func<TSource,TResult>>());

            return result.ToList();
        }
```

-Update 1:
Ok on the server I have an expression

```
Expression<Func<Person, PersonWithBlogPostsDto>> expression1 = person => new PersonWithBlogPostsDto
            {
                DisplayName = person.FirstName,
                Key = person.Key,
                Posts = person.Blog.Posts
            };
```

That gets serialized

```
var serializedExpression = expression1.ToExpressionNode();
```

After being transmitted over the wcf to the server I need to cast the expressionNode back into a Expression> so that I can query the data source of person with the expression generated on the client. I can determine the return type from a string within the expression node. The return type will change depending on the dto being used, so I am unable to set up the casting of

```
Func<Person, PersonWithBlogPostsDto>>
```

ahead of time. In other words I need PersonWithBlogPostDto to be a parameter. The only way that I have been able to come up with to do that is using reflection to call the method.

Comment: Give a concrete example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Reflection was made to do this.  It is completely unclear why you need an alternative.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No problem really, just looking for a faster alternative if I did not need a return type I know I could make and Action using dynamics, I was thinking something like that may exist for this situation.

Comment: I think it's much easier to list all the slower and more painful techniques than it would to try to trump reflection. A few years ago I used reflection in a real-time image processing app and the speed wasn't a concern. If you use a high-resolution timer and get precise timings for individual operations, then perhaps folks here on StackOverflow could help you identify what can and should be optimized. In any case, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not having any performance issues, no need to change.

If you are having or think that will have, you can give a look on

Fasterflect - .NET Reflection Made Fast and Simple

http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/